# Optimizing a 2 parameter distance function on line segments (ACM ICPC Regionals Elim.)

Tags: algorithm, minimization

This problem is a subproblem of a problem posed in the ACM ICPC Kanpur Regionals Elimination Round:

Given 2 line segments bounded by the 2D points `(Pa, Pb)` and `(Pc, Pd)` respectively, find `p` and `q` (in the range `[0,1]`) that minimizes the function

```
f(p, q) = D(Px, Pa) + D(Py, Pd) + k D(Px, Py) where 
                                2 <= k <= 5, 
                                Px = p Pa + (1-p) Pb, 
                                Py = q Pc + (1-q) Pd and 
 D(x, y) is the euclidean distance between points x and y
```

(effectively, Px and Py are points on the line segments and the function encodes the cost of going from Pa to Pd through a connecting link of a cost that is k times the euclidean distance)

Some observations regarding this function:

1. Parallel line segments will always cause atleast one of `p` and `q` to be either 0 or 1
2. <strike>Intersecting line segments will always cause `p` and `q` to locate the point of intersection of the line segments (the triangle inequality can be applied to prove this)</strike>

The question:
In the general case where the lines are inclined and potentially separated, how do we minimize this function?

Comment: you should write this in c or c++ !

Comment: @Svisstack - The language used is not important to me, the algorithm is.

Comment: @Svisstack - Would you require a clarification of the question in C/C++? If so, which part?

Comment: I don't understand observation 2. Counterexample: the two line segments form a tall "X" with Pa and Pd epsilon-close to each other, and the point of intersection (Pi) at both midpoints. Now stretch the X vertically to infinity. Then D(Pa,Pi) + D(Pi,Pd) >> D(Pa,Pd) = epsilon.

Comment: @Steve - you're right. It's a mistake in my observation.

Comment: No problem. Re: your other comment, I think there are many numerical methods for solving this problem. Because this problem is relatively simple, a simpler method may be best. In the competition, how are answers evaluated? What makes a "good" answer?

Comment: Answers are evaluated based on satisfying an accuracy constraint (numerically 10^-5 in this case) as well as satisfying a runtime limit (~1s). I've realized that a simple 2D Binary search by using the gradient of the function as the predicate should suffice. @Steve - Do you have any other alternatives in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to take the partial derivatives of `f` with respect to `p` and `q`, set them to 0, and solve for `p` and `q`.  That will give you a (local) minimum.  If the minimum has `0 <= p <= 1` and `0 <= q <= 1`, you're done, otherwise check the four endpoints (`p=0,q=1`, and so on).

I'm not positive that this will handle all degenerate conditions, but it should be a good start.

Comment: I mulled over it and saw a couple of sites on function minimization. This is indeed the generic method, but getting the analytical solution to the equation pair df/dp = 0 and df/dq = 0 turns out to be really messy. I'm looking for numerical solutions to the problem - possibly using binary search in 2 dimensions or possibly a variant of the Newton Raphson method.